# Penalty for not producing block for more than 24 hours

Tags: block-producer

I'm new to EOS, and was reading the whitepaper [How can developers prevent abusive or spammy transactions on dApps if it's free for users to use?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/259/how-can-developers-prevent-abusive-or-spammy-transactions-on-dapps-if-its-free/261#261) 
And I found that if a block producer does not produce any block for more than 24 hours he is taken out from consideration for producing blocks. However, this part of consensus I was unable to find in the eosio code. 
My question is, is this part actually implemented on EOS? is the BP actually set to inactive automatically? or other BP's have to vote manually to set him inactive?

The only part which I've found till now which mentions setting the BP to inactive after 24hours is libraries/testing/tester.cpp I think this is only for testing purpose and not actually implemented for a production network. I'm not very sure.

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not in the code, but it is the recommendation that the other BPs `unregproduce` the BP who is failing to produce blocks. So far, this feature has never needed to be used because the BPs are all very capable of producing blocks. In the few cases where a BP had an issue that prevented them from producing blocks, they have usually `unregproduced` themselves until the problem was fixed.